# WebDriver - Unable to locate element

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am testing a website where I have to submit the form.
I entered the username, password. Clicked Submit. But even though the form is submitted, I getting the following error message for submit:

`Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"submit"}`

code: `driver.findElement(By.name("submit"));`

I wanted to know why this error occurs.

Comment: Is there an element with **"name"** attribute as **"submit"** in your form (supposedly a button) ?

Comment: The code is as follows<input class="sub" type="submit" style="margin-left:0px" name="submit" value="Login">

Comment: Possibility is there can be more than one matches with the selector you are using. Try `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[type='submit']")` and see how many elements are returned

Comment: Okay.. Like you said, the form is submitted. Then probably you are in a new page where there is no **"submit button**. Of course it will throw the error, in case you are again trying to locate **submit button** when it is not present in the first place

Comment: Please post the code snippet that is clicking on the submit button and validating various page states.

Comment: Yes, a new page is opened. Its repeating the action of submitting the form and throws error and unable to perform actions in the new page.

Comment: You might be using a loop, so the action is getting repeated or else you might have written the code for clicking on the button twice (Human error, happens to most of us :) ). Either way, unless you post the code snippet, it will not be possible to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to know why this error occurs.

The error is occurring because there is no element on the page with the `name` attribute with the value `submit`.

My educated guess, is that you are trying to find the submit button, and getting confused with the `By.name`

`By.name` will, as @Subh stated, find an element by the name.  e.g: `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />`

Give this a try:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[type='submit']")
// careful though, if there are more than one of these, then you need to increase the specificity
```

Comment: The code is as follows                                           <input class="sub" type="submit" style="margin-left:0px" name="submit" value="Login"> I tried with css selector as per the suggestion but still not working:(

Comment: then this is a separate issue.  Is the submit button within a frame?